# Require minimum browser versions for a web application

Tags: php, user-agent, dom4

I have a web application in PHP which in the frontend requires some more modern browser features like the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver). As stated on the site only very new browsers support this feature. The same holds for some HTML5-features I need to rely on.

What I would like to achieve now, is to check server-side with the UserAgent-String which browser the user is running, and if it is below a specific version, redirect him to an info-page where he is informed that he should use a newer browser.

I've been trying now for a while to setup appropriate Regex-Expressions to check the UA-strings against. However, I'm stuck a little bit as the browser manufacturers don't always keep a clean schema - e.g. let's say for an Opera-Browser I would require a minimum version of 12.

- **Opera 12.14 example 1:** Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14
- **Opera 12.14 example 2:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 *Firefox/4.0* Opera 12.14
  This could also be Firefox 4.0.
- **Opera 11.51:** Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; *MSIE 9.0*; Windows NT 6.1; de) Opera 11.51
  This could also be Internet Explorer 9.0.

Also tracking for the same browser and version is tricky as shown in the two examples for Opera 12.14: either it is "Version/12.14" or "Opera 12.14" or some other pretty "random" string. For other browsers the problem is quite similar.

So the question is: how would you proceed?

**Method 1:**
useragentstring.com has an API that I could query each time a user accesses the welcome page and/or logs in. I'm not sure whether this is a good idea in matters of **security** and **app performance**.

**Method 2:**
PHP's get_browser() function in conjunction with browscap.ini. This method can't distinguish between desktop and mobile browsers.

**Method 3:**
An alternative to Method 2 could be [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap) where you can define your own browsercap.ini without depending on a browscap.ini somewhere on the server where you don't have access to.

Or any other method?

I'd be happy for some comments.

Comment: Do not check UserAgent, use JavaScript to check if feature is supported in browser.

Comment: You will greatly frustrate users which you detect incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than keeping your own database of user agents and features, which can be hard to get right, and a pain to keep updated, many developers these days use JavaScript to query whether a feature is available in the browser.

The [Modernizr JavaScript library](http://modernizr.com/) makes this relatively straightforward. [This article](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) goes into more depth about why this approach is a good idea, and shows a few alternative methods of doing feature detection if you don't want to rely on a library.

Comment: Thanks to all the answers and for pointing me into the right direction. I was already using Modernizr but didn't think of it the right way - now I'll do client-side feature detection and then redirect users to an error page if they lack features.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do everything on the server? Use javascript [browser](http://www.whichbrowser.net/) or [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) and use javascript to display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this little ditty in the past (excerpted) :

```
var browsers = [{
        browser : "Opera",
        css     : "o",
        engine  : "Presto",
        rex     : {
                    eng : /(?:Gecko|Presto)\/([0-9.]*)/,
                    brw : /.+(?:Opera|Version).([0-9\.]+)/
          },
        ever    : 0,
        bver    : 0
   },{}]

var UA = function(p_ua) {

    var curr, i;

    for (i in browsers) {
        var r = new RegExp(browsers[i].browser);

        if (p_ua.match(r) && (!!browsers[i].rex)) {
            curr = browsers[i];
            curr.ever = curr.rex.eng.exec(p_ua)[1] || curr.rex.eng.exec(p_ua)[0];
            curr.bver = curr.rex.brw.exec(p_ua)[1] || curr.rex.brw.exec(p_ua)[0];

            break;
        }
    }

    return curr;
}
```

(See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ginomai/j5rhp/%20jsfiddle)). It's not complete, but it was sufficient for my needs at the time. Outside of something like that, *capability* detection on the client side is definitely the way to go - whether it's css, html OR javascript (ie http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/, 1/3 of the way down). I love using regular expressions - but the browser vendors can't be depended on to keep the UA string the same from version to version (let alone follow an actual standard! see : useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).